# Unable to deliver static files in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, windows, django-views

I ran the collect static script and I am still not able to deliver the static files.
My static files folder - `F:\Python\REALESTATE\static` and inside that are all js, CSS, and IMG folders.

I suspect this is not working properly -

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I have faced problems with this before also. I am using windows 10.

My Setting.py files

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'REALESTATE\static')
]
```

My html file:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %} " />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %} " />
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %} " />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/lightbox.min.css' %} " />
```

Comment: What error are you getting, try to get print  of STATICFILES_DIRS variable:
 print(STATICFILES_DIRS)

Comment: I am getting this: F:\\Python\\REALESTATE\\REALESTATE\\static

Comment: ok, so it shows that the static files are fetched from REALESTATE\\REALESTATE\\static directory where as you have the static folder created as F:\\Python\\REALESTATE\\static. The solution is to create static directory with files under F:\\Python\\REALESTATE\\REALESTATE
You may want to run : python manage.py collectstatic

Answer (score 0):

Sir you can try this structure:

MISProject

- MIS
- libraries
- student
- static    <---- Put your static files here and run collectstatic
- static_cdn
- venv

  - manage.py

Add this code to your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
```